# Symfony , Autoloader class was not in it

Tags: php, symfony

**I'm getting this error and I'm getting crazy because of that as well.
I'm using Symfony 3.2.2 framework and Autoloader claims that The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.**

**Stack Trace**

```
throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Trying to autoload a class with an invalid name "%s". Be careful that the namespace separator is "\" in PHP, not "/".', $class));
            }
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('The autoloader expected class "%s" to be defined in file "%s". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.', $class, $file));
        }
        if (self::$caseCheck) {
            $real = explode('\\', $class.strrchr($file, '.'));
```

**Thats my BookType.php;**

```
    <?php

namespace Bookkeeeper\ManagerBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class BookType extends AbstractType{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder->add('title')->add('description')->add('pages');

    }
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
        $resolver->setDefault(array('data_class'=>'Bookkeeeper\ManagerBundle\Entity\Book'));

    }
    public function getName(){
        return 'bookkeeeper_managerbundle_book';
    }



}
```

**That's my BookController.php file
**

```
<?php

namespace Bookkeeper\ManagerBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Bookkeeper\ManagerBundle\Entity\Book;
use Bookkeeper\ManagerBundle\Form\BookType;

class BookController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction(){
        return $this->render('BookkeeperManagerBundle:Book:index.html.twig');
    }
    public function showAction($id){
        return $this->render('BookkeeperManagerBundle:Book:show.html.twig');    
    }
    public function newAction(){
        $book = new Book();

        $form = $this->createForm(new BookType(), $book, array (
            'action' =>$this->generateUrl('book_create'),
            'method'=> 'POST'
        )); 
        $form->add('submit' , 'submit' , array('label' => 'Create Book'));

        return $this->render('BookkeeperManagerBundle:Book:new.html.twig', array(
            'form'=>$form->createView()
        ));

    }
    public function createAction(Request $request){

    }
    public function editAction($id){
        return $this->render('BookkeeperManagerBundle:Book:edit.html.twig');
    }
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id){

    }
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id){

    }
}
```

Comment: And what class is expected?

Comment: The autoloader expected class "Bookkeeper\ManagerBundle\Form\BookType" to be defined in file "/home/huseyinocal/bookkeeper/vendor/composer/../../src/Bookkeeper/ManagerBundle/Form/BookType.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote namespace `Bookkeeeper\ManagerBundle\Form`; instead of namespace `Bookkeeper\ManagerBundle\Form`; (note the extra e in what you wrote)

```
<?php

namespace Bookkeeper\ManagerBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class BookType extends AbstractType{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder->add('title')->add('description')->add('pages');

    }
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
        $resolver->setDefault(array('data_class'=>'Bookkeeeper\ManagerBundle\Entity\Book'));

    }
    public function getName(){
        return 'bookkeeeper_managerbundle_book';
    }



}
```

Comment: My File is called BookController.php not Bookkeeper.Controller.php .I have wrote wrong a little while ago and  edited this.

Comment: I edited my answer with your response comment to @u_mulder

Comment: Thanks you very much for this.I was complicated doubtless.